# 451 4.4.0 Primary target IP address responded with 235 error in exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-server, mail-server, exchange-server-2007

The following error is occurred in the exchange server 2007 and mail are not disseminating to all recipients.

I tried with `get-queue | fl`  commands and also followed some of the online suggestions made for other users. But nothing worked out to fix my issue. 
Can some one help me out to fix this issue with my mail server?

I got this error:

```
NextHopDomain : hub version 15
LastError     : 451 4.4.0 Primary target IP address responded with: "235 00000870YIIGUAYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggY/MIIGO6ADAgEFoQMCAQ6iBwMFAAAAAACjggTEYYIE
                wDCCBLygAwIBBaEPGw1JTkNPSVMuR09WLklOoigwJqADAgECoR8wHRsHU01UUFNWQxsSTUFJTC5pbmNvaXMuZ292Lmluo4IEeDCCBHSgAwIBEqEDAgFMooIEZgSCBGIjDRqya
                dXg4Y1GQAcMZKo9KfI/2l1JPauKHPjVxyi3sP+6PV8wXjzRn36QjnIsLu7OPtzWDRkJBR/VFnJMLT3wTpg0uEe4eAr7kAgJ+mo4vbuFdlYb+ns23tnLO2kyt3dfXgrPF5Ulm4
                C6me734JrfOrkT51UCliUMKmlcDAhcPEmDUagjCg9XmLatKNTn41sFZktRjFs8bXexAacl/Wil+gFI5qZbh9nrs922FUoLhmX1U7dS6xiyH2VHaxCAodcbNh14apN/rK0SvjQ
                Zi+L2bO2RSF3Rx5LO4zAPfn9LAlNQRwQo8U8NR7J1JACBUwe3t3InTRA0TXyJNCxVGZBM5QjgeJFgBRN6pqa6jZyT7tUgURrG1fHFs4fV77jyxgKjxcrUdc5n7MWT77sfLlb4
                Ao5HJukOnWlBVUyoDCDvVarc+8/5VJdWFxnNUkohaVUPnDYMMGiGsadDYy39omsSasFkLShLqE7vBGx3WdsvQQnH2kOTwS4mfbWsuulDUfgHOoBg4AW/fB1oxCUT5E3/siLDd
                urZX/LEjSCmwxbtzzLJ9IGhAlMb+WUUhlZiNb2mn3pZAUlQnDip0ZkXi2nYm71FaTnBb1chScpnpBJ+o30C6yPubBnP562F33sgd/CqB9ZbH4nawrG4pPa6yoVDFgB9lVnQ0h
                EGlcyNotCTdFMuJrqVF/XFwGKPT+V9uxdNtMNqDkXjLNGE7FshmmhAMbPPVtGdpJaPyAx5RKf1IqZRs2aHwU294AdChan+SsxZkruzB3ahiyIlops5j3Ie64lPJOnQdAmT9LU
                WBG4ssEToAILaVfNvgfPx60dh1noK8Ih0plJ0+r7dV7SctqijbRtgyDccKYqrM5z+UjdbTJjzEwq54dljmq2MyEC7lghBcUkzNA0v1gKztXiIDa+vED9Z0u34n5bUghzZCSpF
                41BjMt82S6IKzFfZxVZgW68I3kCvslzRFHmnn0V3ICQBkwrwUoz73l9xnWUqvSyg8khALOMcuyXfrDT3H5Mb/Ar62e6VnOb2RAh7Mc28I3JsbZ6oucv80Xpe9uHTkvNcitUUD
                4lFKyHPv65t6/19lju4clUXC+fbP94uL1I9g8nQlCBWSmQt+QZeCZ5xcBoCh0qb1CexWVihixZPRxcp7Ut+JCt1RCL1IYNJqA7k33xTT7KyXgV8f0BYuck5PdeDMFYVB77dju
                kAlWDpRd2PYOTosswHnF6d1rTQihawC+BOBx2U03jROO57K/xnto/shWxuz4j8kBQHuX+RJfZvOZLtO5AsgmM/34iTe6fitAQ5MVi5R1X7BioxUik9OgXUjRa/ilFvm9JfAe/
                TxYclvNckP3ZtnsLyM3vynitaKIzUPhDotnvfJhZb1hVL69KYl77Bh/b6/wKF8vzoytXHgUkwgaBfvGvugD4oyH0yhzRWaazi905+OkbqwH2pb+/JY11PSQgRxaVYMvvgfcfg
                sDvfjS0CA44oj/Nz0//fAhYYBW6kggFcMIIBWKADAgESooIBTwSCAUsxZR1eKvSuYI6zhYpUMZJQ5cyo/GmW7Zrq9qcFO3pZjdOI9/gGKp9H5pYsmOcEx6zzCfRw1yBsVz7Mh
                BmAITrQ7FslxYzQS/O6TTaJsT2TPL3dfwyOaqM7xv4xtht3GN9vr6KceDhfU7jBC6osgSioL5/HOzTuwpZW7eUg+22PDdLx/1XbTlBcYL9ZVJ73ELgbv/EadMCWwe1VCowKJx
                YZjaZTTiIhPa68Nogxu7QnaXGE7CLUD8LeJuoh3fL1VGMfD+5X/azU8Bla2pqMT1OvUfhuDUK9s/3++tzFUNIVuzYlP+IxVFFM6kSrxlV1Raoywasu0PIczzjQ4hRV3xJ1NEI
                yCuiXSN4oxJP3kq6a/TzFsxURdBbKK5YuNIRmb3t/mTpgihoGXKJPoDwEPpbB55IUBhhDG9t3y7sPEcpo48M4JVAJxslG5GM+0000002CPuzRqM2PPoahT81xmujDkYbkp2uE
                O19dIzolNFXEmmU=." Attempted failover to alternate host, but that did not succeed. Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery f
                ailed to all alternate hosts.

NextHopDomain : Submission
LastError     :
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and the problem was the time between the 2 hub transport servers was greater then 5mins. I synced the time and retried the queue and the mail flowed again.

Comment: This is better served as a comment - on SO. Or, you could include more technical information it might suffice to answer this question.